# How to mark a row in a datatable on button click?

Tags: button, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with the first column containing a delete button for each row. When I click on that button, the "deleted" row is only marked for deletion (in a bean) until changes are saved (by clicking on "save" button). Meanwhile I would like to etc. change row color or remove the delete button in "deleted" row(s)... something to remind me that the row has already been marked for deletion. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, simpler than I thought.

I made css file

```
.red{
    background-color:rgb(250,165,200);
}
```

and added

```
rowStyleClass="#{item.rowState eq 'DELETED' ? 'red' : null}"
```

attribute in dataTable.

Works perfectly!